# Lighttpd server.use-noatime

Tags: lighttpd

I am using lighttpd for my server. On main page lighttpd.net i saw some IO benchmark.
And i saw some config-key:

> server.use-noatime = "enable" 
>   server.max-stat-threads = 2
>   server.max-read-threads = 64

But when i put that config-key to my lighttpd.conf and restart lighttpd
Error show:

> 2012-03-08 07:00:21: (server.c.968) WARNING: unknown config-key:
>   server.use-noatime (ignored) 2012-03-08 07:00:21: (server.c.968)
>   WARNING: unknown config-key: server.max-stat-threads (ignored)
>   2012-03-08 07:00:21: (server.c.968) WARNING: unknown config-key:
>   server.max-read-threads (ignored)

Can anyone help me how to use those config-key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those configs only work in lighttpd 1.5.0 which was never officially released (you can find a pre-release at http://www.lighttpd.net/2007/2/3/lighttpd-1-5-0-pre which you'll note is dated 2007).